# Flutter not sort by double in list

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list I just need to sort it by number.

List look like this

```
I/flutter ( 9048): [{take: 0, give: 20.0, sellerUID: eOYiEjGR2ZGAQAyKV8Ht},{take: 0, give: 40.0, sellerUID: eOYiEjGR2ZGAQAyKV8Ht},{take: 0, give: 10.0, sellerUID: eOYiEjGR2ZGAQAyKV8Ht}]
```

I want to sort this the which give number is greater will come on top then second greater like this.

I am doing like this

```
snapshot.data.sort((a, b) => a['give'].compareTo(b['give']));
```

but its showing this error

```
type '(dynamic, dynamic) => dynamic' is not a subtype of type '((Object, Object) => int)?' of 'compare'
```

Comment: Indicate the type `(a as Map)['give'].compareTo((b as Map)['give'])`

Comment: @Mardel try but didnt work

Comment: You can convert `snapshot.data` to `List<Map>` and then `sort`.

Comment: Specify the type of the data that you receive before you perform the sorting. Because `dynamic` and `object` are different.